# Add click event on linkbutton

Tags: c#, gridview

I have programatically generated linkbutton inside gridview. Here it is

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
     LinkButton nlb = new LinkButton();

     lb.ID = "Ok";                    
     lb.Text = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
     lb.Click += new EventHandler(TotalMinor_Click);
     e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lb);

     nlb.ID = "TotalMinorLink";
     nlb.Text = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
     nlb.Click += new EventHandler(this.TotalMinor_Click);
     e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(nlb);
}

protected void TotalMinor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I expect to call `TotalMinor_Click` function on click on link, but it is not calling the function. What could be the reason ?

Comment: How do you know it's not calling the method. There is nothing inside of it. Are you debugging and trying to stop in the event?

Comment: I put a break point in the method, so, it ought to stop there.

Comment: I had written a response but it said this was deleted. Are you good? Is this question staying here.

Comment: I guess we would need more of your code. Because I am unsure what you have going  on. Some data is triggering this row data and you want to give it a linkbutton with it's own event? Correct.

Comment: The code is too big, what else code do you need ? Have you tried in a linkbutton in the cells of gridview.

Comment: Yeah I have done this before. Honestly don't see a problem right away with how you are adding that to your LinkButton.

Answer (score 1):

The case of events not being fired is ViewState issue and your control should exist and register events on OnInit or OnLoad events of ASP.NET Page LifeCycle. Maybe you should place a hidden div and put your controls inside this div. And in `GridView_RowDataBound` event handler just find those divs and toggle visibility.

Answer (score 0):

On your `LinkButton` inside the `gridview`, it should be like this..

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkbtnID" Text='Text' OnClick="TotalMinor_Click" />
```